# how to copy a consecutive set of none empty characters in vim

Tags: vim

```
${BASE}/test/  other_consecutive_none_empty_characters
```

If the cursor is under the $ sign ,how can I copy "${BASE}/test/" as a whole and paste it 
somewhere else in vim ? I don't want to use the human-eye-letters-counting solution if that is the only solution I'd rather like to hit the keyboard charcter by charcter .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> would be the most correct solution.  <kbd>y</kbd> means "yank" (i.e. copy to buffer), and <kbd>E</kbd> - "up to the end of the WORD", which is, up to the next whitespace character.

Personally, I prefer typing <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> - <kbd>y</kbd>ank <kbd>i</kbd>nner <kbd>W</kbd>ORD.  It works the same way, but the cursor may reside anywhere inside the WORD, not just on the dollar sign.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>y</kbd> Yank <kbd>W</kbd> WORD:

```
yW
```

From `:help W`:

> A WORD consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white space.  An empty line is also considered to be a WORD.

Comment: No matter how long you use vi, there is always something you didn't know :)

I have been using w like a sucker all this time!

Comment: Using `W` will get you the space after the word too - see Pavel's answer!

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> , i.e., `y`, `t`, followed by space. `t` can be thought of as "till".  You can select with `vt`, delete with `xt`, etc.